# How can I write to CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA on a Citrix 2008 server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, citrix

My application stores configuration data that applies to all users in a subdirectory of the directory returned by SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA). This directory is read only to regular users, so the program allows write access to that configuration only, if the user is an administrator.

This works fine on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8, but apparently doesn't (at a customer's site) on a Citrix 2008 server. So something must be different within a Citrix environment. But what?

The path returned is c:\ProgramData (the sams as in Windows 8) and the same (administrator) user who cannot write to this directory from my program, can edit that same file with Notepad.

What am I missing?

Comment: If they can edit the file in Notepad, but your app cannot save it, it sounds as though the problem is not what you think it is.

Comment: The application uses TJvInifileStorage and I just now found out that that component eats exceptions that occur e.g. when calling Flush and the OnError event is not assigned. (Stupid idea, in my book.) I have now added an OnError event so hopefully I will get some actual error messages next time.

Comment: I only have the user's description of what he did. I would not put it past him to have started Notepad with a different user or with "Run as administrator" without telling me.

Comment: What you describe does not sound totally convincing so I do wonder about the accuracy of your users reports. Obtaining some hard diagnostics would appear to be the next step.

Comment: As an aside, does this mean that you are forcing your users to run this app elevated? Many apps that write into common appdata have their install program create a sub-folder and give that sub-folder a permissive ACL. So that standard user can write to that folder.

Comment: Currently yes, I am forcing my users to run the application elevated if they want to change this particular setting. This is nothing that the regular users do but part of the configuration process. And it is not done during installation because it must be done when a new search path for data is added to the system. The regular user should *not* be able to change this setting.